# Is it correct to use the word "then" to imply something of the past?

Tags: grammar, semantics

I am trying to identify something that was once a new thing. I used the word "*then*" to imply the subject as something that is already a past. But I am not sure if this is grammatically and semantically correct. For example:

> The team wanted to show the features of the *then* new Windows XP.

In this case, Windows XP *was* new. It is *not* new now. However, does the word "*then*" imply this meaning?

Also, should it be "*then* new", or "*then-new*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. It means new at the particular time in the past which the speaker or writer has in mind. You don't need a hyphen.

Comment: I agree that a hypen isn't necessary, but it would still be acceptable, wouldn't it?  (I think it reads a bit more clearly with the hyphen, but it seems that's mere personal preference.)

Comment: @J.R. If it's not necessary, why use it? I see it as a distraction rather than as an aid to comprehension.

Comment: Erin's link provides an abundance of both – but I very much appreciate your minimalist view regarding punctuation. :^)

Comment: @J.R. Pragmatic rather than minimalist, I like to think.

Answer (score 4):

This looks correct to me. You can find many examples of your ["then new" usage on Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Za8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%2B%22the+then+new%22&oq=%2B%22the+then+new%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...6932.7250.0.7429.4.4.0.0.0.1.101.334.3j1.4.0...0.0.nVAxMJQbjsI).

Also, your use of "then new" is used 9 times in the usage examples of the OED 2nd Edition, which should be reassuring.

If you still have doubts, a slight rephrasing might help:

"The team wanted to show the features of Windows XP, which was new at the time."