# How do I refer to something that happened in the past, but it was recent at that time?

Tags: past-tense

The sentence is something like this:
The program was controversial when it was launched in 2017, mostly due to the (then recent) social climate.

Comment: Hello, Chantelle. Do you mean social climate then obtaining, or that which had just been supplanted?

Comment: What's wrong with *then recent*?

Comment: Everything that happened in the past was recent at the time. @jsw29

Comment: @Xanne, true, *then* will often be redundant because the context is likely to make it clear that one is speaking of something then recent rather than now recent. The point of my comment was to question the need for replacing the phrase that appears in the question with something else.

Comment: "...mostly due to the social climate at the/that time." "Then recent" seems awkward, to me.

Answer (score 1):

> the (then recent) social climate.

My first thought:

> the then social climate.

I was tempted to overanalyse, but [Is it correct to use the word "then" to imply something of the past?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68817/11504) offers a comparable example:

> The team wanted to show the features of the then new Windows XP.

The accepted answer was that *then new* is fine so in your case, you might write (without parentheses):

> the then recent social climate.

– or, I reckon, simply:

> the then social climate.

Comment: Or even "the social climate then." which, to me, flows better.

Answer (score 0):

Contemporary describes some point in the past, but the surrounding events are present tense relative to the time period. For example, contemporary music in the 1930s was jazz, where as contemporary music now is pop.

In the same context, you can reference an event in 2017 and speak of the contemporary (which will refer to 2017) social climate.

Answer (score -1):

> The program was controversial when it was launched in 2017, mostly due to its [**novelty**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novelty).

This means that the thing itself was new.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : something new or unusual
>   // the *novelty* of a self-driving car
>   **2** : the quality or state of being novel : NEWNESS
>   // an uncritical acceptance of *novelty* as advance
>   — H. M. Jones A toy's novelty soon wears off.

---

If you want to emphasize the social climate instead:

> The abolition of slavery in the U.S. was controversial when it was enacted in 1865, mostly due to the social climate **at the time**.

However, you can also retain the use of *recent*, since it's relative to the time period established in the sentence itself:

> In 1866, the **recent** abolition of slavery was having an impact on commerce and social attitudes.